# measure memory used by static local variables in C code

Tags: c, code-metrics

Are there any static code metrics tools that measure total size of static local variables in c functions. The tools that I explored report the stack size but not the size of the static local variables. Is there another option apart from using linux objdump and parsing the output?

Comment: On linux you can use [readelf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) for the executable image file and [pmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) for the running process to see what's been allocated for what kind of use from a higher level memory footprint perspective. Usually things are done on page boundaries so you're not going to see anything super-tightly conforming to your specific memory footprint on a UNIX OS AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX `size` command can be used for this purpose. The size of the data section is the size of all data in static storage (except data declared const on some targets).